# Install Java EE 6 on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos6, winscp, checksum, java

Having problems installing Java EE 6 in CentOS 6 x32.

I have removed all previous version of Java and freshly installed temporally jdk1.6.0_34.

So my $PATH variable goes to:

> /usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/jdk1.6.0_34/bin/

Everything seems good to run:

> [root@localhost opt]# ./java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-linux.sh

but it spits the following errors:

```
Extracting the installer archive...
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 3807229 but got 66969 bytes)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:386)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:156)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:100)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:934)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:850)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:240)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1147)
Extracting the installer runtime...
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:223)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:154)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:100)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:934)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:850)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:240)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1147)
Extracting the installer resources...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./Product/Packages/Resources.zip (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:236)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1147)
Extracting the installer metadata...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./Product/Packages/metadata.zip (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:236)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1147)
chmod: cannot access `product-installer.sh': No such file or directory
sh: product-installer.sh: No such file or directory
```

Checksum:

```
[root@localhost opt]# md5sum java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-linux.sh
9299039e3daefff779875721ec8288c3  java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-linux.sh
```

The reason was a bug with WinSCP (transferred from my Windows PC to Linux), transferred many files and checksum changed...

Changed to Filezilla and checksums matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the same file from oracle site and it's md5sum is --

```
 [chida@localhost Downloads]$ md5sum java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-linux.sh
 2a79c24baed38f847def9c4e3398b40a  java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-linux.sh
```

I ran the installer script on my 64bit Fedora 17 and it runs well and opens the graphical installer.

Do verify if the checksum matches mine else it's something else.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that winscp by default transfers .sh files in ascii mode, hence your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Java EE SDK you have downloaded is not complete.

Comment: Very similar or same error happens with this `java_ee_sdk-6u4-unix.sh`

Comment: If possible, get the md5sum for the package and verify with what you downloaded.

Comment: I downloaded the same file from oracle site and it's md5sum is -- 2a79c24baed38f847def9c4e3398b40a